# Salary position asking me to check on a process at 2 AM

Tags: salary, after-hours

Am I at risk of termination for not doing it?

Recently started a new job and it's been fine mostly the first few months but they've been asking me to check a process at 2 AM and cancel it if it's too big to finish by morning. I told them that the latest I'd be willing to do any work is 9 PM and usually I work from 7:30 to 4. They didn't mention the 2 AM thing when I was hired. And being salary I don't mind working late or on weekends but at reasonable hours. 2 AM is ridiculous to me, why not have someone west coast or even India check it.

Comment: If this is a once in a *long* while thing, then I'd go with it.  If this is an every day thing then that's ridiculous.  When I've been faced with problems like this in the past, I prefer to automate a solution rather than just keep doing the silly manual thing.  If _you_ can determine that there is going to be a problem and cancel the job, then an automation script should be able to do the same thing without anyone having to get up at 2 AM!  Work smarter, not harder.

Comment: @jwh20 Write an answer of it. This is correct and complete.

Comment: Why not automate it?

Comment: How often are you required to do this?

Comment: Ring the manager at 2.10 asking for his confirmation to cancel the process… :)

Comment: What is your location?

Comment: If the task can randomly be cancelled for spurious reasons at regular intervals, consider whether it's needed at all..
Or, find a way of hosting or fixing the task so it always finishes.
Or, get up in the morning, and if the task is still running, cancel it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Am I at risk of termination for not doing it?

If you refuse to do what you are asked to do, then certainly you put yourself at risk of being terminated.

That said, suggest alternative ways of dealing with this issue (speed the process up, have someone else cancel it, automation, etc.) and see if they still insist that you do it.

Only your manager can know for sure if they consider this a "fireable offense" or not. Based on your use of the phrase "west coast or even India", I assume you are in the US. In most US states you can be fired for any reason.

If it comes down to it, you may need to decide if this requirement means you no longer want this job, and start looking elsewhere.

Comment: _"If you refuse to do what you are asked to do, then certainly you put yourself at risk of being terminated."_ in most civilized countries this would not fly as a reason for termination, considering the OP seems to work office hours, instead of some kind of nightshift or on-call duty.